# Javascript: Regex not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I was trying my hands with regex. I want to capture a scenario when there are more than 2 numbers after decimal point. But I wasnt able to get any output from the below javascript code where as my regex works fine with online regex editors

```
 var str = "1234.788"; 
    var re = new RegExp("\d+");// simple basic regex: no output
//  var re = new RegExp("\.d{3}")   //regex to capture number when 3rd numberr is entered after decimal: no output
    console.log(str.match(re));
```

Comment: Double escape backslash: `\\d+`, or better use a regex literal: `/\d+/`

Comment: ^^^ or use regex literal syntax as there is no dynamic variable to use in regex. `var regex = /\d+/`

Comment: not with regex but if you do:
var str = "1234.788"; 
var arr=str.split('.');
var len=arr[1].length;
if (len>2) alert("much");